# Revert a filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am applying an AngularJS filter programmatically like so:

```
filtered = $filter('number')(value, 2);
```

This will give me something like `5,000.00`. I need a way to take the filtered value and strip out the formatting so I can get `5000` from `5,000.00`. I can do this with javascript but thought there might be a way to do this using Angular that I am not familiar with.

Thoughts?

Comment: uses parseFloat, but before you need to remove the comma: parseFloat(filtered.replace(/,/, ''))

Comment: why not leave the value as number and only use number filter in the view for display only?

Comment: @Dustin If you're ok with our answers, please accept one, or provide some feedback. Thanks

Comment: My question must not be very clear - no one is answering it. "I can do this with javascript but thought there might be a way to do this using Angular that I am not familiar with". Basically, yes everyone, I know HOW to do what I am asking using javascript. I thought there might be mechanism in Angular to "unfilter" a string. I used the number filter as an example, but I need to do this using multiple string filters.

Answer (score 1):

How about to create own custom filter?

```
app.filter('round', function() {
  return function(input, count) {
    var output;

    //Your code here
    output = Math.floor(input, count); //something like that
    return output;

  }
});
```

and

```
filtered = $filter('round')(value, 2);
```

or in html:

```
<span ng-bind="myVal | round:2"></span>  <!-- or <span> {{myVal | round}} </span> -->
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se_panfilov/6pbxLun7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do in vanilla js or jQuery, you can do it in AngularJS, most of the times.
So yes you can convert float/double into int in AngularJS, like this

in controller :

```
$scope.floatNum1 = 12.00
$scope.floatNum2 = 10.89
```

In View :

```
{{floatNum1 | number:0}}  // it will render 12
{{floatNum2 | number:0}}  //it will render 11
```

Hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just parse as float without commas:

```
var filtered = '5,000,000.00';
var source = parseFloat(filtered.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

I used Joaozito Polo's answer but added `g` modifier to the RegExp because without it it will replace only 1 comma.